# Redirecting all queries to secondary in sharded cluster in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

How to redirect all queries to secondary in sharded cluster rather than setting readpreference variable while making connection to mongo router. In short, mongo router redirect all read queries to secondary which is primary by default.

Comment: No it doesn't. The read preference you set will be respected

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to execute read only query on sharded replica set in mongodb](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25723692/how-to-execute-read-only-query-on-sharded-replica-set-in-mongodb)

Answer (score 0):

You do this with the readPreference connection string option, or query option (if your driver supports this). A connection to the mongos router with a readPreference set gets honoured, when selecting which member of each shard's replicaset gets queried, just like if there was no mongos router in the way.